# How do I use firesass from middleman

Tags: css, firebug, sass, middleman

How do I enable sass's '--debug-info' switch from middleman?

I've been using sass for creating css, and firesass for debugging the sass.

I've just started playing with middleman, which makes use of sass.

The problem is, I can't figure out how to enable the '--debug-info' switch from middleman.

A search for "middleman firesass" give this result:
https://github.com/middleman/middleman/issues/127

This shows a block of ruby that could possible address the issue. But I don't know what to do with that block.

Answer (score 3):

Place the following in your config.rb

```
compass_config do |compass|
  compass.sass_options = {:debug_info => true}
end
```

Comment: If you want to avoid the extra markup from being added to your `middleman build` site, you need to be sure to set it to `false` in your `configure :build do` section of the config.rb file.

Comment: To disable on build: `configure :build do
  compass_config do |config|
    config.sass_options = {:debug_info => false}
  end
end
` (https://github.com/middleman/middleman/issues/706)